# Multi-store setup on lighttpd

Tags: multistore

I am trying to do a multi site setup in a magento instance running on lighttpd. I have followed [this](https://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup) guide, including filling in the new secure- and unsecure-urls in system/configuration/web/. After doing the setup I have cleared the cache and restarted the webserver. For some reason I get redirected to the default website.

It has come to my attention that lighttpd does not support .htaccess files and I am not sure how I to check if htscanner is installed or if that helps at all in this specific case. Any pointers on this would be greatly appreciated! :)

Why am I being redirected to the default website? Is it because ligttpd does not set the environment variables I have specified in the .htaccess file using setenvif? If so, how can I fix that? Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out... add code to the index.php file instead!

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'domain.name.com':
    case 'www.domain.name.com':
        $mageRunCode = 'website_code';
        $mageRunType = 'website';
    break; }
```